# Sharepoint 2013 used as a company DAM

Tags: 2013

We are considering building our digital asset management system over Sharepoint 2013. We have CCA 3-4TB of digital assets (90% images and few videos) currently scattered across various shared drives which isn't sustainable for much longer. We were also considering purchasing some dedicated system such as WebDAM, but these are quite expensive and contain number of features we wouldn't make use of anyway so I was wondering if appropriately adjusted Sharepoint image library 2013 would do...

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: From personal experience, I wouldn't recommend it. Look at a true digital asset management system.

Comment: Did you finally buy WebDAM and integrate it with SharePoint 2013? We are now attempting to integrate SharePoint to WebDAM through REST API. Can you give any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am really not sure if SharePoint alone would suit a DAM system with such sizing specs. Even if you use BLOB the boundaries and limits like file size (2 gb) and content database still apply. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx for further details.

> If you are using Remote BLOB Storage (RBS), the total volume of remote BLOB storage and metadata in the content database must not exceed the 200GB limit.

Also the file upload in SharePoint is not optimized for such big files. You will need WFEs servers with huge RAM as during the upload IIS put the file in there until upload is complete.

A possible solution would be to leave the files itself in a classic file system (NAS, SAN, etc.) and integrate them into SharePoint. There are some 3rd party solutions out there, that can do that job.

Maybe let us know how you solved that challenge finally. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 has new asset library provides better features for managing videos. However, your file size also requires a BLOB solution.

Check out the asset library at,
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee414276%28v=office.15%29.aspx

For the BLOB solution, you can check out StoragePoint.

John